# Use Matlab to Login to Webpage and Download File

Tags: java, matlab, cookies, web

Using Matlab, I'm trying to download a file from a website that requires you to login first.  The file I'm trying to download is [here](http://www.standardandpoors.com/prot/spf/docs/indices/SPUSA-500-USDUF--P-US-L--Constituents.xls) (http://www.standardandpoors.com/prot/spf/docs/indices/SPUSA-500-USDUF--P-US-L--Constituents.xls)

I'm guessing this involves cookies and hacking into the java code in the urlwrite function.  Has anybody done this or does anybody have ideas on how I get started?  Is there some standard way to login and get a cookie, and then pass the cookie back with future requests?

Comment: I tried this once and gave up, instead launched an external Perl process to do the work for me.

Comment: I believe [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317931/how-do-i-provide-a-username-password-to-access-a-web-resource-using-matlab-urlrea) has the answers you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would think system, rather than tool.  I agree with Alex - Perl to download, maybe Pentaho/Kettle to parse/process.  Especially if you're going to do more of this.