# Matlab using Java openStream(url) get :Java exception occurred: java.lang.​NullPointe​rException

Tags: java, matlab

I want to download one file from a URL using Matlab.

According to this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/294528. all works fine until i go to the line:

```
is = jurl.openStream;
```

This gave one error says **Java exception occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException.**

Edit:

```
Company='Abc'; 
Depar='Fin'; 
url1='com/';; 
url2='/download_h5_Depar='; 
url3='.h5' ; 
url=strcat(url1,Company,url2,Depar,url3); 
links=url; 

% copy files to local folder 
[pathstr, name, ext ] = fileparts(links);
% name changed here 
name=strcat(Company,'-',Depar);
```

Error message:

```
at com.mathworks.net.transport.MWTransportClientPropertiesFactory$1.getPasswordAuthentication(MWTransportClientPropertiesFactory.java:86)
at java.net.Authenticator.requestPasswordAuthentication(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$1.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.privilegedRequestPasswordAuthentication(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getServerAuthentication(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
```

Anyone can help? thanks

Comment: What stream are you trying to open?

Comment: one url address. it is one file which connects to URL..so I want to open that file and copy the file to my local file ..

Comment: I understand what you want to do... However, I've tried to use the url of this question, and things worked like a charm. So again, what stream are you trying to open?

Comment: my url is .h5... and the file name is different with the one in the URL. So i defined the downloaded file name, it works, but it stops in this line as mentioned above.

Comment: Please add the code YOU use to the question.

Comment: This is all what I have editted:                       Company='Abc';
Depar='Fin';
url1='http://com/'; 
url2='/download_h5_Depar='; 
url3='.h5' ;
url=strcat(url1,Company,url2,Depar,url3);

links=url;


% copy files to local folder

    [pathstr, name, ext ] = fileparts(links);
   % name changed here 
    name=strcat(Company,'-',Depar);

Comment: Do you understand what I mean...it is difficult to show it clear here...

Comment: Finally..it ended up with the authentication issue ...solved     [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317931/how-do-i-provide-a-username-password-to-access-a-web-resource-using-matlab-urlre)