# matlab websave and urlwrite with authentication and proceeding with options

Tags: matlab, urlread

I have a question about downloading a file from a website using matlab. It is actually a four step as following.

1) There is a web authentication for reaching the website:
http://ngawest2.berkeley.edu/users/sign_in?unauthenticated=true

Example account that has access to the site:
Username0 = 'ibk2@email.arizona.edu';
Password0 = '12345678';

2) After authentication/login is passed, there is a dropdown menu to choose an option and "submit" button to proceed. For example, dropdown menu is

"Select models to generate target spectrum:"
- "No Scaling"
- option 2
- option 3

so I want to select one of the options, e.g., "No Scaling" and then enable "submit" button.

3) After submitting in previous step, it takes me to another view with lots of other menu and options, but I want to just fill in one text-box where you type in the file names you want to download, the name of box is "RNS(s)" and for example I want to able to fill in like this

RSN(s):  5818,5819,5820

then there is another submit button with a name "Search Records" to submit RNS names above to be searched.

4) Finally after step 3 is done, there is another button that enables to download all the RNS files in a zip file, the button name is 
"Download Time Series Records (metadata+spectra+traces)"

I am not sure how hard this question is. I have used ulrread and urlwrite with authentication similar to the one in this page: 
[How do I provide a username/password to access a web resource using Matlab urlread/urlwrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317931/how-do-i-provide-a-username-password-to-access-a-web-resource-using-matlab-urlre)

Is this possible to do in matlab?

I hope someone knows a way to go around to download some files the way I described above. I really appreciate any comments.

Baha

Comment: You need to look at the page source in step 3 to see what URL it POSTs the form to. This is the form that you'll want to submit using MATLAB's tools. Without being able to access the site, it's hard to give you specific help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Suaver. Could you please try this username and password to have access to the site.  
email: ibk2@email.arizona.edu & password: 12345678

Comment: Hi Suever, have you had a chance to look at this?